# Python regex to match many tokens in sequnece

Tags: python, regex

I have a test string that looks like

> These are my food **preferences** mango and I also **like** bananas
> and I **like** grapes too.

I am trying to write a regex in python to return the text with such rules:

- Search for the keyword: preferences
- make a group (words 1:7) until the word 'like' >> Repeat this step as much as possible
- a final group (words 1:7)

My current expression is: (live: https://regex101.com/r/1CSSNc/1/ )

```
(?P<Start>\bpreferences\b)(?:\s*(?:(?P<Name>\w*)\s*){1,7}like)*?(\s*(?P<Last>\w*\s*){1,7})
```

which returns

```
Match 1     18-64   preferences mango and I also like bananas and 
Group Start 18-29   preferences
Group 3     29-64    mango and I also like bananas and 
Group Last  60-64   and
```

I expected/wanted the output to be:

```
Match 1     18-64   preferences mango .. grapes too
Group Start 18-29   preferences
Group 3     29-64    mango and I also 
Group 4     xx xx    bananas and I
Group Last  60-64    grapes too
```

My implementation is missing some concepts here.

Comment: If you need help please explain what you need to get as output given your current string. It is not understandable what you are trying to get, and why.

Comment: I updated with my need/expectation of the output

Comment: What about Group "Name"? Also, why do you mix numbered and named groups? It would be much more straight-forward to capture using one type of capturing groups. Note that there are some problems with your expected output, e.g. `Last` group cannot contain two words, it only captures `\w*\s*` pattern that matches zero or more word chars and then zero or more whitespaces.

Comment: I suggest you use [something like this in Python](https://ideone.com/IWk8z1), see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1CSSNc/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?P<Start>\bpreferences\b)(?P<Mid>(?:\s+\w+(?:\s+\w+){0,6}?\s+like)+)(?:\s+(?P<Last>\w+(?:\s+\w+){1,7}))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1CSSNc/3).

*Details*:

- `(?P<Start>\bpreferences\b)` - Group "Start": a whole word `preferences`
- `(?P<Mid>(?:\s+\w+(?:\s+\w+){0,6}?\s+like)+)` - Group "Mid": one or more repetitions of

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `\w+(?:\s+\w+){0,6}?` - one or more word chars and then zero to six occurrences of one or more whitespaces and then one or more word chars, as few as possible
  - `\s+like` - one or more whitespaces and then the word `like`
- `(?:\s+(?P<Last>\w+(?:\s+\w+){1,7}))?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `(?P<Last>\w+(?:\s+\w+){1,7})` - Group "Last": one or more word chars and then one to seven occurrences of one or more whitespaces and one or more word chars

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/7b8rml):

```py
import re
text = "These are my food preferences mango and I also like bananas and I like grapes too."
pattern = r"(?P<Start>\bpreferences\b)(?P<Mid>(?:\s+\w+(?:\s+\w+){0,6}?\s+like)+)(?:\s+(?P<Last>\w+(?:\s+\w+){1,7}))?"
match = re.search(pattern, text)
if match:
    print(match.group("Start"))
    print( re.split(r"\s*\blike\b\s*", match.group("Mid").strip()) )
    print(match.group("Last"))
```

Output:

```py
preferences
['mango and I also', 'bananas and I', '']
grapes too
```